# App to automatically tap when certain notifications/screens are shown?

Tags: android, automation, notification

Is there an app that will automatically tap Android notifications like the incoming call screen (it's in fullscreen).

What app that can perform auto tap to that screen automatically?

Comment: It's getting more clear... thanks!  Are you looking for a recommendation on the Android platform or a different OS?

Comment: In Android please.

Comment: You should be able to do that using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en). Tasker  can listen to notifications by a particular app and once the notification shows up you can execute actions using its own UI or use AutoInput which can swipe, tap, record macros and whatnot. Also, you need to see [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).